# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader at app launch

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception, dalvik

I've got a pp that was made by a different company to make some updates on it but I can't get it going. I've struggled with this problem for nearly 10h straight now and have gone through a lot of threads suggesting different solutions for this error but no luck.

I've tried to clean and rebuild and alter my manifest file in different ways but no success. But I still think that the problem might be in the manifest file but not certain.

```
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.visma.falck.android.assistance.FalckAssistanceApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.visma.falck.android.assistance.FalckAssistanceApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.visma.falck.android.assistance-1.apk]    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:490)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3901)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:135)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1098)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.visma.falck.android.assistance.FalckAssistanceApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.visma.falck.android.assistance-1.apk]    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:951)    
12-11 09:47:47.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9756):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:481)
```

**EDIT:**
After updated manifest according to ρяσѕρєя K I get a different error in the same style:

```
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.visma.falck.android.assistance/com.visma.falck.android.assistance.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.visma.falck.android.assistance.SplashScreen in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.visma.falck.android.assistance-1.apk]    
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.visma.falck.android.assistance.SplashScreen in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.visma.falck.android.assistance-1.apk]
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
12-11 10:23:08.917: E/AndroidRuntime(9949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1777)
```

New manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.visma.falck.android.assistance" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="1.4">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

        <!-- To access connectivity information -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <!-- To access the phone number -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!--   To allow debugging on all models -->
    <!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission> -->

        <!-- For all services, e.g. https, google maps -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <!-- For google maps -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <!-- For google maps -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

        <application 
           android:icon="@drawable/application_icon" 
           android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/theme">

<activity android:name=".FalckAssistanceApplication" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">
                android:allowBackup="true" 
                android:debuggable="false"
    </activity>



            <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.SplashScreen"
                android:configChanges="orientation" android:debuggable="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- wheel menu -->
            <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.menu.MenuActivity" android:debuggable="true"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
            </activity>


            <activity android:name="Contact" android:debuggable="true"/>


        <activity android:name="Info" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".information.TermsOfUse" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".information.Tip" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".information.TryAgain" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name="Registration" android:debuggable="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" android:configChanges="orientation"/>


        <activity android:name=".userprofile.UserInformation" android:debuggable="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.Abonement" android:debuggable="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.AddVehicle" android:debuggable="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.AddSubscription" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.EditVehicle" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.EditVehicleLastRegistration" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.EditVehicleMileage" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.EditVehicleRegistration" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".userprofile.VehicleType" android:debuggable="true"/>

        <activity android:name=".order.WaitForCallActivity" android:debuggable="true"  android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.AssistanceMap" android:debuggable="true" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.OngoingAssistanceMap" android:debuggable="true" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.Compass" android:debuggable="true" />
        <activity android:name=".order.CompassActivity" android:debuggable="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.Order" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.return.customer"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".order.Problem" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.SubProblem" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.MyVehicle" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.Trailer" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.WaitForCall" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.FalckIsOnItsWay" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.PeopleInTheCar" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.PersonalInfo" android:debuggable="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.EnterMobileNumber" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".order.SelectAddress" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <receiver android:name=".order.WaitForCall$PhoneCallEndReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.waitforcall.endcall" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".order.PhoneCallHandlingService">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.waitforcall.endcall"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- My Info: Subscriber -->
        <activity android:name="MyInfoSubscriber" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <!-- My Info: Welcome -->
        <activity android:name="MyInfoWelcome" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <!-- My Info: Registration -->
        <activity android:name="MyInfoRegistration" android:debuggable="true"/>

        <activity android:name="FrontPage" android:debuggable="true"/>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.Main" android:debuggable="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.station.StationList" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.falck.assistance.station" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.station.StationListActivity" android:label="Find falck-station" android:debuggable="true">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.station.StationDetail" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.falck.assistance.station" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.station.StationMap" android:debuggable="true" android:configChanges="orientation"/>

        <activity android:name="StationActivity" android:debuggable="true"></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.garage.GarageList" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.falck.assistance.garage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.garage.GarageListActivity" android:debuggable="true"/>

        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.garage.GarageDetail" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.falck.assistance.garage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.garage.GarageMap" android:debuggable="true" android:configChanges="orientation"/>

        <!-- Rental car: list -->
        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.rentalcar.RentalCarList" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.falck.assistance.rentalcar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.rentalcar.RentalCarStationListActivity" android:debuggable="true"/>

         <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.rentalcar.RentalCarListActivity" android:debuggable="true"/>


        <!-- Rental car: details -->
        <activity android:name="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.activity.rentalcar.RentalCarDetail" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.falck.assistance.rentalcar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.rentalcar.RentalCarMap" android:debuggable="true" android:configChanges="orientation"/>

        <activity android:name=".activity.rentalcar.MyBenefitsCarRental" android:debuggable="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.garage.MyBenefitsGarage" android:debuggable="true"/>


        <activity android:name=".Test" />


        <service android:name=".service.MainDataService" android:debuggable="true"
            android:process="com.visma.falck.android.assistance.service.MainDataService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.create.user" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.update.user" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.reset.user" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.user.completion" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.customer" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.garage.list" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.falck.station.list" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.rental.car.station.list" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.create.assistance" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.ongoing.assistance" />
                <action android:name="com.visma.falck.get.text" />
            </intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </service>

       <!--  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

declare `FalckAssistanceApplication` as

```
    <activity android:name=".FalckAssistanceApplication" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

instead of adding in < Application tag

```
 <application 
       android:icon="@drawable/application_icon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/theme" 
       android:name=".FalckAssistanceApplication"  <<--remove 
                                 <<-- FalckAssistanceApplication from here
       android:allowBackup="true"  
       android:debuggable="false">
  ///.....
```

Comment: @PaperThick : post your new log and also Manifest for more help

Comment: @PaperThick : in which package you have `SplashScreen` Activity ? try as `.SplashScreen `instad of `com.visma.falck.android.assistance.SplashScreen` in manifast.xml

Comment: It's in `com.visma.falck.android.assistance`tried the change but same error message .